# Text entry ios question

Tags: cocoa-touch, string, ios, text

I have two UILabels in a view that display my band and song name as strings. I am working on also adding the option to change either of these strings manually. I want to keep it as is, and I've added 2 buttons to manually enter a song name or band name. The thing is, all the text editing as far as I understand it needs to have actual TextField or TextView to bring up the keyboard etc.

I just want to touch one button for "enter song name" and be given a keyboard and when enter is hit, replace the string in the uilabel with that string, and the same for enter band name uibutton, and change the uilabel again.

Problem is in the docs I don't really understand how to do this. Does anyone have an idea about text entry in ios and can give me a pointer/tip on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going to have to do is replace the label with a text field and set that as the first responder when the user presses the button. You will need a class that is the delegate of the text field so you handle enter in the textFieldShouldReturn method to resign first responder on the text field (to close the keyboard) and change the text field back to the label view and update its contents.

Answer (score 3):

Just Declare your label Global and implement in implementation method
Take all song and all album data in array 
and display all data in table view
now by using Delegate method of

> - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>     change the text of Label as u want

```
@interface songViewController ()
{
UILabel *bandLabel;
UILabel *songLabel;
NSArray *bandData;
NSArray *songData;
}
@end
@implementation songCreateViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
{
    bandLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    bandLabel.frame=CGRectMake(40, 580, 500, 30);
    bandLabel.text=@"Join group as";
    [self.view addSubview:bandLabel];

    songLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    songLabel.frame=CGRectMake(40, 580, 500, 30);
    songLabel.text=@"Join group as";
    [self.view addSubview:songLabel];
}
   #pragma mark Table view Delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    if(tableView==albumTableView)
    {
        bandLabel.text=[bandData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
        if(tableView==songTableView)
    {  
       songLabel.text=[songData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    }
@end
```

Comment: It is quite good but not the correct one what question wants. but it will help  if any one wants to change label according to row name.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieve by many ways..

1) you can use **hidden** in your button methods to hide label and show textView.

2) you can use textField in place of label, make textfield.editable=NO and when button is pressed just clear the textfield by **textfield.text=nil** and make textfield editable.

Try these..

Answer (score 0):

```
You want like when user touch on button you want to add text and button should be look like UILable. is it your objective? 
If I am right you can achieve this thing to add gesture in uilable, you don't need to add button and handle tab method you can change the text.
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         print("Hello World")
      }
```